# Device orientation strange behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, device-orientation

I have my Universal app ready and I set the device orientation to portrait only.
On the iPhone it's okay - only portrait, but on the iPads it is still can rotate to landscape. I double checked that I unticked the landscape left/right and left only portrait.
Actually it's not a big problem for me, because I use Auto Layout and it still looks okay when in landscape but maybe somebody can provide a reasonable explanation.
I use:
objective-c
XCode 6.1.1
testing devices iPhone 5c and iPad mini with Retina display

Comment: Are you sure you've set the orientation for both iPhone *and* iPad?

Comment: Oh my! You're right! In the targets > general I had Deployment info > Devices set to Universal and checked only portrait. When I've changed it to iPhone there was only portrait but in iPad all check marks were ticked! I think it's not obvious. It's better to uncheck from both iPhone and iPad when choosing Universal. Anyways @LyndseyScott thank you very much for the response it helped me!

Answer (score 1):

If somebody have a problem like I described above, just check the device orientations you need in ALL possible variants like iPhone/iPad/Universal.
Thanks @LyndseyScott